# Error on deploying a site template

Tags: deployment, solution-package

I have a web application in which I have few document libraries, lists, picture libraries, workflows and few webparts. The webparts are created using visual studio with the feature site scoped. WorkFlows are created using SPD. Everyting working fine in my local SharePoint server. I want to copy my web application to a different server. For this I saved the site template Site Actions-> Save Site as template, saved the wsp to my desktop. Then I took the wsp to the other server machine where i created a webapplication. Then using PowerShell command added the solution using Add-SPSolution command. When trying to install using Install-SPSolution command I got an error: 
 This solution contains no resources scoped for a web application and cannot be deployed to a particular web application

I tried to change the scope of webpart feature to Web/WebApplication but encountered error when tried to deployed using visual studio.

How can I deploy the wsp in a different SharePoint Server machine?

Answer (score 0):

the error tells you that in your wsp package you try to add there are no web scoped resources. When you try to deploy your package you do not have to specify URL parameter. Try to remove this. It should look like:

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity $SolutionPackageNameNew -GACDeployment
```

If you do this with a script you can check if WSP have web scoped resources:

```
# Try to get new package on the site
$solution = Get-SPSolution | where-object {$_.Name -eq $SolutionPackageNameNew}

# check to see if new solution package has been installed
if($solution -ne $null)
{
   # Install solution
   if ($solution.ContainsWebApplicationResource) 
   { 
      Install-SPSolution –Identity $SolutionPackageNameNew –WebApplication $webApp -GACDeployment
   }
   else
   {
      Install-SPSolution –Identity $SolutionPackageNameNew -GACDeployment
   }

   do
   {
      # Wait for deployment to be completed
      Start-Sleep -s 1
   }
   while($solution.JobExists)
}
```

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks. the soln is globally deployed. how can i create a site collection with this solution?

Comment: I suppose you have a template (custom?) or out of the box. Do it using central administration or check this out: http://virtualizesharepoint.com/2012/01/03/create-a-new-sub-site-in-sharepoint-using-powershell/

Comment: I had saved the site template out of box Site Actions->Save Site as template and saved the solution from solution gallery.

Comment: Go to central administration and try to create a site collection. But it seems to me that you do something  wrong...

Comment: So no upvote or marked as answer? Thanks

Comment: Andrew Adamich.. Thanks a lot for the effort... but i could arrive at a soln yet..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8202/discussion-between-suja-shyam-and-andrew-adamich)

Comment: Sorry, but unfortunately I have no a lots of time... Try to see this article. Maybe it helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx